A floor-fraction identity of $2$: $\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\rfloor - \lfloor\frac{x}{2d} \rfloor=\lfloor \frac{x+d}{2d}\rfloor + 1$ (doesn't work without 2)
Conjecture.  For all $d \in \Bbb{N}$ and $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ the following identity holds:
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x}{2d} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{x+ d}{2d}\right\rfloor + 1
$$
Desmos demonstration.
Usually, this will not occur (two floor-of-fractions for anything other than a halving - a factor of $2$ in one of the denominators), because the steps are no longer of equal length all the way to infinity / negative infinity or in other words the steps are not "uniform".
Question. How can we prove this?
Attempt. By floor-to-fraction formula:
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x}{2d} \right\rfloor = \\
\frac{x - (x)_d}{d} -\frac{x - (x)_{2d}}{2d} = \frac{2x - 2(x)_{d} - x - (x)_{2d}}{2d} \\
\ = \frac{x - 2(x)_d - (x)_{2d}}{2d}
$$
where $(x)_d = x \mod d \text{ (minimum standard residue taken.)}$, but when I expand the other side similarly:
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{x+ d}{2d}\right\rfloor + 1= \frac{ x + d - (x+d)_{2d} + 2d}{2d}
$$
Thus my goal is now to prove that:  $$2(x)_d - (x)_{2d} = 3d - (x+d)_{2d}$$
Seems kinda of hairy to me!  Am in need of a trick...  Also I tried pluging in $x = 0, 1$ and this equality doesn't even hold!  So how could Desmos show that they're indeed equal?

The correct identity (which is what you've typed in Desmos but not in your question) is
$$\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x}{2d} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{x-d}{2d}\right\rfloor + 1.$$
Letting $u=\frac x{2d}$, the identity becomes
$$\lfloor2u\rfloor=\lfloor u\rfloor+\left\lfloor u-\frac12\right\rfloor+1.$$
We split into two cases: if $u=n+t$ for some integer $n$ and some $t\in[0,1/2)$, then
$$\lfloor2u\rfloor=2n=n+(n-1)+1=\lfloor u\rfloor+\left\lfloor u-\frac12\right\rfloor+1.$$
On the other hand, if $u=n+t$ for some integer $n$ and some $t\in[1/2,1)$, then
$$\lfloor2u\rfloor=2n+1=n+n+1=\lfloor u\rfloor+\left\lfloor u-\frac12\right\rfloor+1.$$

I really like your proof.
